# XSLT for Arabic language

Tags: xml, xsd, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

Is there a method to create XSLT to publish Arabic XML to pdf. Can it be combined with the XSLT that I already have for English. 
Do we necessarily have to use Apache FOP for this or can it be done without it also.

Also, could you please explain with an example of how the write-mode(rl) can be used in the XML for Arabic.

Thanks you for your support.

Comment: To convert to pdf, you always need an xsl-fo processor like apache fop or commercial alternatives.

Comment: In addition to what Stefan Hegny said, if you already have a stylesheet for English content, I think you just need to configure a font with the Arabic glyphs (otherwise, your text characters are going to be replaced by `#`glyphs). According to [FOP's website](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/complexscripts.html), in most cases there should be **no** need to use `writing-mode` or other language-related properties.